# Adicionar valores a um cursor em PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, pl-sql

Boa noite.
Estou a tentar definir os valores de um cursor em PL/SQL, contudo um dos valores nunca é preenchido. Neste caso, o número qtd_diasSemConsumo nunca tem conteúdo, contudo todos os outros têm, o que presumo que seja por estar a usar um select diferente para o qtd_diasSemConsumo. Ao testar o código recorrendo a blocos anónimos, todos os valores se encontram corretos, menos este que se encontra vazio.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fncObterRegistoMensalCamareira(mes int, ano int DEFAULT (EXTRACT (year from SYSDATE()) - 1)) return SYS_REFCURSOR AS

idCamareira camareira.id%type;
nomeCamareira funcionario.nome%type;
valorTotal_consumos number;
dataPrimeiroConsumo date;
dataUltimoConsumo date;
qtd_diasSemConsumo number;

cursorConsumos SYS_REFCURSOR;

BEGIN
    
    OPEN cursorConsumos 
    
    
    FOR SELECT cam.id, func.nome, sum(linha.preco_unitario) as Valor_Total, 
    min(linha.data_registo) as DATA_PRIMEIRO_REGISTO,
    max(linha.data_registo) as DATA_ULTIMO_REGISTO
    FROM camareira cam, funcionario func, linha_conta_consumo linha
    WHERE cam.id = func.id AND EXTRACT (month FROM linha.data_registo) = mes AND EXTRACT (year FROM linha.data_registo) = ano
    AND cam.id = linha.id_camareira
    GROUP BY cam.id, func.nome, linha.quantidade;
    
    
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO qtd_diasSemConsumo
    FROM (select to_date('01-02-2020' ,'dd-mm-yyyy')+level-1
     from dual 
     connect by level <= TO_CHAR(LAST_DAY(to_date('01-02-2020' ,'dd-mm-yyyy')),'DD')
     MINUS
     SELECT DISTINCT linhaC.data_registo
    FROM camareira cama, linha_conta_consumo linhaC
    WHERE cama.id = linhaC.id_camareira AND EXTRACT(month FROM linhaC.data_registo) = mes AND cama.id = idCamareira);

RETURN cursorConsumos;
EXCEPTION
  when no_data_found then
  return null;
END;
```

Comment: O qtd_dias não é retornado nem usado no cursor !? O que se quer exatamente !?

Comment: Acho estranho as duas pesquisas associadas ao mesmo `CURSOR`. Que tipo de informação se pretende receber? Se se pretende receber dois conjuntos de dados deves declarar a saída de dois SYS_REFCURSOR